# Use-cases for the WAT and WATP AMPScript functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Do any of you fine folks know anything about the [**WAT() and WATP()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/wat.htm) AMPScript functions?

I'm looking for a real use-case outside of the official documentation:

> Returns the values of the Web Analytics Tracking (WAT) parameter with
>   the specified external key. Contact Marketing Cloud Support to set the
>   external key values in the Web Analytics Connector. The function
>   substitutes optional parameters for calls to the WATP function within
>   the tracking parameter set in the Sender Profile. The WAT call
>   parameters must use constant or numeric values. Variable, attribute,
>   field, and faction values don't allow job-level resolution to the
>   desired link query string parameters

In all of the times I've worked with Marketing Cloud Support to configure the Web Analytics Connector, I've not once heard anything about a customer/external key for the parameter names.

I assumed that if you have a `et_cid` parameter in your WAC string, that you could override the value like this:

```
%%=WAT("et_cid","whee")=%%
```

That doesn't appear to be the case. The above code results in the following error:

```
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an WAT function call. 
See inner exception for details. The specified tracking parameter does not exist.  
Tracking Parameter Name: et_cid 
Function Name: WAT 
Parameter Name: ParameterName 
Parameter Ordinal: 1 
Parameter Type: Text 
Submitted Value: et_cid
```

I'm waiting on a response back from SFMC Support.

And then there's the **WATP()** function.  It's even more mysterious.

Who's got the deets?  You?